# Use Python and Selenium to output text of only selected index

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having some trouble with creating a program that automates a checkout process.  I'm using python 3 along with Selenium.  The program parses through a range of dates, which are outputted on the page as available four available slots.  If none are available on the current page, it will click the 'next' button and search through the next four dates.  If it gets to the end of the available date ranges and finds nothing, it'll wait thirty seconds and reset and do it all over again.

I've got the majority of this done, except for two issues:

1) I'm trying to add an argument that, when included, will go beyond the base functionality (which is to simply notify the user via text using Twilio), and complete the full checkout process.

This is the python code I'm using:

```
def find_available(args):

    dates_available = True
    spaces_free = False
    free_spaces = ""
    while not spaces_free:
        while dates_available:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            spots = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.ss-carousel-item')
            for spot_index, spot in zip(range(date_range), spots):
                if spot.value_of_css_property('display') != 'none':
                    spot.click()
                    available_dates = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.Date-slot-container')
                    for available_date in available_dates:
                        if available_date.value_of_css_property('display') != 'none':
                            selected_spot = available_date.find_element_by_css_selector('#slot-container-UNATTENDED')
                            if 'No doorstep delivery' not in selected_spot.text:
                                free_spaces = selected_spot.text.replace('Select a time', '').strip()
                                spaces_free = True
                            else:
                                print(selected_spot.text.replace('Select a time', '').strip())

        if spaces_free:
            print('Slots Available!')
            if args.checkout:
                client.messages.create(to=to_mobilenumber, 
                    from_=from_mobilenumber, 
                    body=free_spaces)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Soonest available')]").click()
                time.sleep(1.5)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Continue']").click()
                print('Your order has been placed!')
            else:
                client.messages.create(to=to_mobilenumber, 
                    from_=from_mobilenumber, 
                    body=free_spaces)
                print('Your order time will be held for the next hour.  Check your date and confirm!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="auto-checkout")
parser.add_argument('--checkout', '-c', action='store_true',
                    help="Select first available slot and checkout")
args = parser.parse_args()
find_available(args)
```

**Expected Behavior**

If the program is launched using the '--checkout' or '-c' argument, then, once 'spaces-free' is set to true, it should send a text with the text within the 'free_spaces' element.  It should then move on to the next phase, which would be a selecting of a radio button that contains the text 'Soonest available' (as in select the first available radio button that contains an available time slot), and then click the continue button.

**Actual Behavior**

The program will run, find an available time slot, then simply move on to the next days, never attempting to select a radio button and move forward in the checkout process.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me that you never set the `dates_available` to `False` inside your `while` loop:

```py
        while dates_available:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            spots = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.ss-carousel-item')
            for spot_index, spot in zip(range(date_range), spots):
                if spot.value_of_css_property('display') != 'none':
                    spot.click()
                    available_dates = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.Date-slot-container')
                    for available_date in available_dates:
                        if available_date.value_of_css_property('display') != 'none':
                            selected_spot = available_date.find_element_by_css_selector('#slot-container-UNATTENDED')
                            if 'No doorstep delivery' not in selected_spot.text:
                                free_spaces = selected_spot.text.replace('Select a time', '').strip()
                                spaces_free = True
                            else:
                                print(selected_spot.text.replace('Select a time', '').strip())
```

So you'll never exit the `while` loop. If you don't want to rewrite the whole logic, you could set `dates_available = False` right after you set `spaces_free = True`. That would allow exiting the `while` loop, but you might need a `break` or two to exit the `for` loops too.

If you want a failsafe behavior, you should refactor your code for smaller functions and if you want only the first available something, you could just `return` from the function with the first available data.

Something like this maybe?

```
def find_available(args):

    def get_a_date():
        while True:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            spots = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.ss-carousel-item')
            for spot_index, spot in zip(range(date_range), spots):
                if spot.value_of_css_property('display') != 'none':
                    spot.click()
                    available_dates = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.Date-slot-container')
                    for available_date in available_dates:
                        if available_date.value_of_css_property('display') != 'none':
                            selected_spot = available_date.find_element_by_css_selector('#slot-container-UNATTENDED')
                            if 'No doorstep delivery' not in selected_spot.text:
                                return selected_spot.text.replace('Select a time', '').strip()

                            else:
                                print(selected_spot.text.replace('Select a time', '').strip())

    free_spaces = get_a_date()

    print('Slots Available!')
    if args.checkout:
        client.messages.create(to=to_mobilenumber,
            from_=from_mobilenumber,
            body=free_spaces)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Soonest available')]").click()
        time.sleep(1.5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Continue']").click()
        print('Your order has been placed!')
    else:
        client.messages.create(to=to_mobilenumber,
            from_=from_mobilenumber,
            body=free_spaces)
        print('Your order time will be held for the next hour.  Check your date and confirm!')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to provide a detailed answer! The issue I was experiencing was indeed due to not canceling out of the while loop.  I'm running into some smaller issues now, but i think I'll look into refactoring the code once I have that sorted out.  Thanks again!